# appendTo() animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Trying to achieve any moving effect while appending an element from one to another with jQuery or jQuery-UI.

```
<div id='div1'><div id='i-am-moving-slow'></div></div>
<div id='div2'></div>

$('#i-am-moving-slow').appendTo('#div2');
```

Please help. Thanks.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/5936t/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could append a clone of the element to the new spot, but keep it hidden.  Animate the original element into the new spot, then remove the old element, and show the new one.

I made a plugin to do this.  Try this:

```
$.fn.animateAppendTo = function(sel, speed) {
    var $this = this,
        newEle = $this.clone(true).appendTo(sel),
        newPos = newEle.position();
    newEle.hide();
    $this.css('position', 'absolute').animate(newPos, speed, function() {
        newEle.show();
        $this.remove();
    });
    return newEle;
};


$('#i-am-moving-slow').click(function() {
    $(this).animateAppendTo('#div2', 1000);
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5936t/36/

Comment: Looks clean, but I thought with jQuery I could do it with less coding. =)

Comment: Problem is, there is no built-in method to do what you want.  So, I made one :-)  From now on, you can just use `animateAppendTo` :-P

Comment: doesn't work if the item was 100% in width inherit from the parent container. the cloned item comes out at full size

Comment: @mikeymeows see my answer for a solution that does work in that case.

Comment: awesome.. should be added to jquery official .

Comment: Does it alter $this position style?

Answer (score 2):

I know this problem is long-solved, but I decided to improve upon Rocket's answer.  I needed to animate the behavior of not only appendTo, but prependTo, insertBefore and insertAfter, and I also wanted the ability to customize easing and provide a callback, much like you can with `$.fn.animate()`.

Also, my function leaves behind the original element rather than its clone, behaving exactly like appendTo.  So if you have any existing references to the element lying around in your script's variables, they will not break.

I also use position: relative rather than position: absolute to do the animation, so if the element's width was 100% of its container it won't jump out and take up 100% of the window during the animation.  However, at the end of the animation it will jump to 100% of whatever its new container's width happens to be.

Here's my solution:

```
$.fn.animateTo = function(appendTo, destination, duration, easing, complete) {
  if(appendTo !== 'appendTo'     &&
     appendTo !== 'prependTo'    &&
     appendTo !== 'insertBefore' &&
     appendTo !== 'insertAfter') return this;
  var target = this.clone(true).css('visibility','hidden')[appendTo](destination);
  this.css({
    'position' : 'relative',
    'top'      : '0px',
    'left'     : '0px'
  }).animate({
    'top'  : (target.offset().top - this.offset().top)+'px',
    'left' : (target.offset().left - this.offset().left)+'px'
  }, duration, easing, function() {
    target.replaceWith($(this));
    $(this).css({
      'position' : 'static',
      'top'      : '',
      'left'     : ''
    });
    if($.isFunction(complete)) complete.call(this);
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
// basic usage
$("#i-am-moving-slow").animateTo('appendTo', '#div2');

// advanced usage
$("#i-am-moving-slow").animateTo('insertAfter', '#some-other-div', 'linear', function() {
  console.log("animation completed on ", this);
});
```

`duration` and `easing` will be delegated to the `animate` call, so if you leave them out they will be passed in as `undefined` and jQuery will use the defaults.  `complete` gets called after the element replacement happens at the end of the animation, and sets `this` equal to the element being animated, just like `$.fn.animate()`'s callback does.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you want

**HTML**

```
<div id='div1'><div id='i-am-moving-slow'>i-am-moving-slow</div></div>
<div id='div2'>div2</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#div2')
.append($('#i-am-moving-slow')
.css({'margin-left':-$(this).width()+'px'})
.delay(500)
.animate({'margin-left':'0px'}, 'slow'));​
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/q94VF/1/).

If you want to append a copy then you should clone it and [here is another example](http://jsfiddle.net/q94VF/2/) using clone.